# Show footer when reaching bottom of page

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, footer

I saw some similar questions, but they didn't give me a solution. I would like my footer show (slideUp) when reaching the bottom of the page and hide again when scrolling towards the top. Now i'm using a script that shows the footer after a certain amount of scrolling.

Here the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/foroloca/afgp3ctg/6/)

Does anyone know how?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10) {
    $( 'footer').slideDown(300);
} else {
    console.log('there');
    $('footer').slideUp(300);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    var height;
    var trigger = 350;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        height = $(document).height()-$(window).height();
        console.log(height+" "+$(this).scrollTop());
     if ($(this).scrollTop() > height - trigger) {
      $( 'footer').slideDown(300);
     } else {
      $('footer').slideUp(300);
     }
    });
```

For better performance, put the window height calculation and document height calculation outside of scroll function and run it instead once after load (`$(){}`) and recalculate it on window resize (`$(window).resize(function(){}`)

Comment: Thanks mate! I think this works the best for me. It is not so sensitive when reaching the bottom and toggles hide/show/hide/show etc. Thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

Try this check working [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/afgp3ctg/8/)

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            $('footer').slideDown(300);
        } else {
            $('footer').slideUp(300);
        }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Compare `$(this).scrollTop()` to your window/body height and not to a fixed value.